# How can I see jboss console with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, jboss

I started jboss-5.1.0.GA server with maven2, is there a possibility that I can see what is happening in the console. I'm using eclipse plugin to run maven. Is it possible to see console in eclipse or elsewhere?

Here is what I mean by console :

[image]

Is it possible to see this output somewhere? I took this screen shot when manually running jboss.

When I start the server with maven here is what I get :

```
[INFO] [war:war]
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp[snrf] in [C:\HOME\c0mrade\Workspaces\Eclipse 3.5 Classic\snrf\target\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in[337 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\HOME\c0mrade\Workspaces\Eclipse 3.5 Classic\snrf\target\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] [jboss:hard-deploy]
[INFO] Copying C:\HOME\c0mrade\Workspaces\Eclipse 3.5 Classic\snrf\target\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] [jboss:start]
[INFO] Starting JBoss...
[INFO] [install:install]
[INFO] Installing C:\HOME\c0mrade\Workspaces\Eclipse 3.5 Classic\snrf\target\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\HOME\c0mrade\.m2\repository\org\trialofmaven\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And that is it. nothing is happening..

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to see this output somewhere? I took this screen shot when manually running jboss.

I'm don't think that the jboss-maven-plugin redirects the logs anywhere so you'll find them in

```
$JBOSS_HOME/server/<your_server>/log
```

Just in case, note that cargo has support for this (here, I'm getting the console output in `cargo.log`):

```
<plugin>    
  <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>    
  <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>    
  <version>1.0</version>    
  <configuration>    
    <container>    
      <containerId>jboss5x</containerId>    
      <home>${jboss.home}</home>    
      <append>false</append>    
      <log>${basedir}/target/jboss5.x.logs/cargo.log</log>    
      <timeout>300000</timeout> <!-- 5 minutes -->    
    </container>    
    <configuration>    
      <type>existing</type>    
      <home>${jboss.home}/server/default</home>    
      <properties>    
        <cargo.jboss.configuration>default</cargo.jboss.configuration>    
        <cargo.rmi.port>1099</cargo.rmi.port>    
        <cargo.logging>high</cargo.logging>    
      </properties>    
    </configuration>    
    <wait>false</wait>    
  </configuration>    
  ...
</plugin>
```

P.S.: I really wonder why you don't start JBoss with the WTP from Eclipse by the way.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent Thank you for your answer Pascal. I found that about server.log as well, I'm trying to write program which will read the server.log then when it changes print the difference .. probably its not the best idea, but since I need console (cause I'm using simple update protocol). Can you tell me what is WTP by the way?

Comment: @c0mrade The Web Tools Platform (WTP) Project *extends the Eclipse platform with tools for developing Web and Java EE applications. It includes source and graphical editors for a variety of languages, wizards and built-in applications to simplify development, and tools and APIs to support deploying, running, and testing apps.* http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/

Comment: I'll accept your answer for your effort thank you, I must bring jboss online with maven ...

Comment: @c0mrad If reading the logs in server/my_server/log is not what you're looking for, maybe cargo is a better option then.

Comment: Hi @PascalThivent Could you please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904614/jboss-console-log-in-eclipse) about console log of JBOSS?