# JBOSS console log in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jax-rs

I am a beginner in JBOSS and I created several RESTful service using JAX-RS.

1. How can I see in the **console** the information about the requests that JBOSS receives?. I mean something like this, when I use **Python's SimpleHTTPServer**, I can see this:

[image]
How can I do the same thing with JBOSS? I use Eclipse for the development, and I'd like to see this kind of info in the **console of Eclipse**.

2. `System.out.println()` seems doesn't work with JBOSS, I cannot see the output in the console of Eclipse. But I like to use `System.out.println()` for the debug. How to make this work with JBOSS in Eclipse?

Comment: That's probably related to some JBoss logging configuration. Do you have any log at all? In my company, calls to `System.out.println()` will be printed to the console, but when using Log4j, only `info` and above will be printed.

Comment: Could you please tell me the right configuration to do to make System.out.prinln() print directly to the console? Any idea about the first question? Thanks a lot!!!